Woocommerce create shortcode to display total quantity of all items sold for a shop
I'd like to get the total quanitty of all items ever sold to create a shortcode to call on in a counter.
I have used the below to call on total number of orders but now I want to get a combined total number of items ever sold from all orders.
    function display_woocommerce_order_count( $atts, $content = null ) {
    $args = shortcode_atts( array(
        'status' => 'completed',
    ), $atts );
    $statuses    = array_map( 'trim', explode( ',', $args['status'] ) );
    $order_count = 0;
    foreach ( $statuses as $status ) {
        // if we didn't get a wc- prefix, add one
        if ( 0 !== strpos( $status, 'wc-' ) ) {
            $status = 'wc-' . $status;
        }
        $order_count += wp_count_posts( 'shop_order' )->$status;
    }
    ob_start();
    echo number_format( $order_count );
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'wc_order_count', 'display_woocommerce_order_count' );

Thank you you for helping

I don't think there is any existing method for that. You will need to fetch your order objects, loop over them and get their order items, and then sum up the quantities for those ...

As Cbroe said had to filter through each completed order, and sum the order items
// Define shortcode to display total quantity sold
function total_quantity_sold_shortcode() {
// Initialize total quantity sold
$total_quantity_sold = 0;

// Get all completed orders
$orders = wc_get_orders( array(
    'limit' => -1,
    'status' => 'completed'
) );

// Loop through each completed order
foreach ( $orders as $order ) {
    // Get order items
    $order_items = $order->get_items();
    
    // Loop through each order item
    foreach ( $order_items as $item ) {
        // Get quantity sold for each item
        $quantity_sold = $item->get_quantity();
        $total_quantity_sold += $quantity_sold;
    }
}

// Return total quantity sold
return $total_quantity_sold;
}
add_shortcode( 'total_quantity_sold', 'total_quantity_sold_shortcode' );

